# Finding the dimension of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $U$ and $W$ are distinct four-dimensional subspaces of a vector space $V,$ where $\dim V = 6.$ Find the possible dimensions of $U \cap W.$

I have tried like this.

$\dim U = 4 = \dim W$

Since $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$ whose dimension is $6$ then $\dim (U+W) ≤ 6$

Using $\dim ( U \cap W) = \dim U + \dim V - \dim(U+W)$ , I get dim $( U \cap W) ≥ 2$ but it can't be greater than $4.$ Therefore the possible values are $2, 3$ and $4.$

Please correct me if I have done anything wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot that $U$ and $W$  are distinct, so that $\dim(U+W)\ge 5$. As a consequence,
$$8-6\le\dim(U\cap W) \le 8-5.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider bases $B_U=\{u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4\};  B_W= \{w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4 \}$ for $U,V$ respectively. This guarantees you a dimension $4$ or larger, since each of $B_U, B_W$ are linearly independent. Since $U\neq V$ , there is at least one vector $u_j \in B_W$ that is not in the span of $B_U$ , and at most two such vectors, since the dimension of $V$ is $6$ . If there is just one such vector then $Dim( U \cap V)=5$ , if there are two such vectors, then $Dim(U \cap V)=6$.